# full width of column if sum is below 12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the snippet below I have three columns in a row. First one takes 1/2 of the row width. However, it might be the case that dynamically the red and blue columns will be removed from the DOM or added to the DOM.

**Is there some option in Bootstrap that in this case (only a single col-sm-6 element is in one row) the column takes the full width anyway?**

**I am looking for a css bootstrap solution** and I want to avoid the usage of js in this case; with js you could easily add the propper css class (col-sm6 / col-sm-12) dynamically.

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    </div>
    <!--The following two columns are not always there (dynamically change). 
    If the following two columns are not part of the dom the green one should 
    automatically span the whole width. However if the two next columns are 
    present the green one should only take half of the row-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- the following row represents the case, where the two columns have been 
  removed from the dom. However, all classes and sytles used for the element:
  <div class="col-sm-6"> should be the same like above! -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `col-sm` instead of `col-sm-6`, `col-sm` gives your columns auto width
If you want your first column takes 1/2 of the row width you can do that by adding css 
 `min-width: 50%;` to that column look my snippet below

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.width--half {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm width--half">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    </div>
    <!--The following two columns are not always there (dynamically change). 
    If the following two columns are not part of the dom the green one should 
    automatically span the whole width. However if the two next columns are 
    present the green one should only take half of the row-->
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- the following row represents the case, where the two columns have been 
  removed from the dom. However, all classes and sytles used for the element:
  <div class="col-sm-6"> should be the same like above! -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="box" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```